# how can import style sheet for components from public folder. and components files are in src/components/files then my app.js look like

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS.

When I load my page, I get this error. Please advice me how to import style for component from public folder.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header'; 
import './App.css'; 
import  './public/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css';   
class App extends Component {  
   render() {   
     return ( <div className="App"> 
        <Header />      
        </div>    
     );  
   } 
}
export default App;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have not posted an error message.

Comment: Please post the error message. Also let us know how you're building the app. If using create - react - app it would bundle css automatically. Else make sure to use css-loader if you're using webpack

Answer (score 0):

You should not put css files in public folder because webpack doesn't read the public folder it will only read the files inside the src folder [Public folder(ReactJS)](https://medium.com/@jenniferdobak/the-public-folder-and-favicons-in-create-react-app-8dc2cc1d492b).
So it is better to add your stylesheets in src folder & access it from there.